# I need to show a warning pop-up while user tries to log-out, using Warden callback, Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise, warden

Warden::Manager.before_logout ?I have the following warden callback in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  auth.session[:signout] = true
 end
```

In my application controller I have this action, which is called by a before_filter

```
def user_logs_out
  if session[:signout]
    display_sign_out_popup = true
 end     
end
```

Then using my java script, I am trying to a show modal pop-up. But apparently, session[:logout] is not becoming true at all. Can I not access session variables set by
     Warden::Manager.before_logout                                    in application_controller.rb ?

Comment: Shouldn't you just trigger the JS when a person clicks on the logout link instead of after?

Comment: Can you let me know how to set a bolean to JS variable in view on button click, that should be available to application.js

Comment: No no, I was thinking something like binding an event to the logout button which pops out the sign out popup and then taking action from there. Not so good example is: <a href="http://logoutlink" onclick="confirm('Really logout?')">Logout</a>